# Get certain value from arrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

EDIT:

I attempted to create something that could do what I wanted it to do, but I got an error

```
String namn = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write persons name");
String dele = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Yes or no? (Ja/nej)");
int pos = personLista.indexOf(namn);
personLista.get(pos).setDelegat(dele);
System.out.println("Done!");
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
at java.util.ArrayList.elementData(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at finnish.jovo.main(jovo.java:29)
```

Doest that mean it couldn't find the name in the list?

---

I am trying to think of how to properly make a method that fetches a certain arrayList item depending on my input string.

So if I'm f.e. trying to get said value by writing the name in an input box.

Object:

```
protected String namn, enamn, kårtill, mötdel;
public Person(String namn, String enamn, String kårtill, String mötdel) {
    this.namn=namn;
    this.enamn=enamn;
    this.kårtill=kårtill;
}
public String getNamn(){
    return namn;
}
public String getKår() {
    return kårtill;
}
public void setNamn(String namn){
    this.namn=namn;
}
public void setDelegat(String mötdel) {
    this.mötdel=mötdel;
}
```

List:

```
static List<Person> personLista =new ArrayList();
```

Essentially what I am trying to accomplish in somewhat gibberish code:

```
String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Write persons name");
if (name exists in list) {
get position of name
String truefalse = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("True or false?");
setDelegat(truefalse) in said item
}
```

Would appreciate some help!

Comment: you could just use a `Map<String, Person>` instead of a `List<Person>`

Comment: you just have to iterate through the list and return the position when you find what you need...

Answer (score 0):

use glazedlist and apply filter.Using glazed list filter you can acheive this.check http://www.glazedlists.com